# How can I perform full recursive directory & file scan?

Tags: c#, .net, search, recursion, filesystems

here is my code:

```
    private static void TreeScan(string sDir)
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {
                //Save file f
            }
        }
        TreeScan(d, client);
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't get the **FILES** of the **sDir** *(Starting Directory)* it only gets the Folders and the Files in the Sub Folders.

**How can I make it get the files from the sDir too ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
private static void TreeScan( string sDir )
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles( sDir ))
    {
        //Save f :)
    }
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories( sDir ))
    {
        TreeScan( d ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 49):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use the overload of `GetFiles` that allows you to specify that it searches subdirectories.

```
string[] files 
    = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Finally someone with some sense.

Comment: Yes but recursion fails on first protected with a folder System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: if you don't require a search pattern, you can use an asterisk (*) for search pattern to return all directories

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your code. For one, the reason you never saw the files from the root folder is because your recursed before doing and file reads. Try this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    TreeScan(@"C:\someFolder");
}

private static void TreeScan(string sDir)
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + f); // or some other file processing

    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        TreeScan(d); // recursive call to get files of directory
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```

like in [This sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx), wich contains a complete implementation of what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your GetFiles loop should be outside the GetDirectories loop. And shouldn't your TreeScan stay inside GetDirectories loop? In short the code should look like this:

```
private static void TreeScan(string sDir)
{
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        TreeScan(d, client);
    }
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
    {
        //Save file f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Fx4 and above the `EnumerateFiles` method will return all files with efficient memory management, whereas `GetFiles` can require max resources on big directories (or drives).

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir.Path, "*.*");
```