# Full directory listing in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I perform full recursive directory & file scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604885/how-can-i-perform-full-recursive-directory-file-scan)

I can't find any informations, how to create a full directory listing in C#, including all files inside and all its subfolders's files, i.e:

```
c:\a.jpg
c:\b.php
c:\c\d.exe
c:\e\f.png
c:\g\h.mpg
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327)("C:\*.*", [SearchOption.AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448));

This will return an array of [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo) objects, which include a Name and FullName property for the filename.

That being said, I would not do this on "C:\", as you'll return a *huge* array, but this technique will work correctly on an appropriate folder.

If you're using .NET 4, I'd recommend using [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343) instead, which will return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an array.

Note that the above code will most likely fail, however, as it requires full permissions to search the file system.  A SecurityException will be raised if you can't access specific parts of the file system you're trying to search.

Also - if you're only interested in the *file names* and not the full `FileInfo` information, you can use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) instead, which returns an `IEnumerable<string>` with all of the relevant filenames.

Comment: That's going to return a gigantic array...

Comment: @Kirk Woll Let's hope that he doesn't actually plan to keep those files directly on C:\ :)

Comment: I'm hoping that "C:\\" isn't the search string here, and was just used as an example...

Answer (score 0):

There is an [MSDN Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974) with code examples to do just this.

This is the money:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir) 
{
    try 
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
            {
                lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```