# Find dir paths for a file

Tags: c#

I have a file path (it is a virtual file system path) and I want to find files with a name "test.txt" from parent dir. to its root dir/

string test = "test.txt"
Let say I have a path : root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.cs

Now, if I do

```
string parentDirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(file); //Here I get dir4
string filePath = Directory.GetFiles(parentDirectoryName, test ).FirstOrDefault(); //I get the path of the text.txt if it is present or i get null.
```

But now, I want to go until root (and see if there is any file named test.txt) and if yes, get the path of all those files.

O/P should be `List<string>` with all file paths from current dir. to root dir. for a file named "test.txt"

How to do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604885/how-can-i-perform-full-recursive-directory-file-scan

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this out:

```
string test = "test.txt";
string somePath = @"C:\Users\mikes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CS_Scratch_WindowsFormsApp2\CS_Scratch_WindowsFormsApp2\Form1.cs";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(somePath);

List<string> testMatches = new List<string>();            
DirectoryInfo di = fi.Directory;
while (di != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Checking: " + di.FullName);
    string candidate = Path.Combine(di.FullName, test);
    if (File.Exists(candidate))
    {
        testMatches.Add(candidate);
    }
    di = di.Parent;
}

Console.WriteLine("Matches:");
foreach(string path in testMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Checking: C:\Users\mikes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CS_Scratch_WindowsFormsApp2\CS_Scratch_WindowsFormsApp2
Checking: C:\Users\mikes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CS_Scratch_WindowsFormsApp2
Checking: C:\Users\mikes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects
Checking: C:\Users\mikes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017
Checking: C:\Users\mikes\Documents
Checking: C:\Users\mikes
Checking: C:\Users
Checking: C:\
Matches:
C:\Users\mikes\Documents\test.txt
```

Comment: Can I do `.parent` in vfs ? My filePath is of vfs.

Comment: I have no idea if it'll work in VFS, sorry. Try it out and let us know what happens!

Answer (score 0):

[`Directory.GetParent(string path)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=net-6.0) is the usual way to get a parent directory in .NET. You can use it to "walk up" the filesystem to the root, something like this:

```cs
string startPath = @"C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\file.cs";
string fileName = "test.txt";

DirectoryInfo? currentDirectory = Directory.GetParent(startPath);

while (currentDirectory != null)
{   
    string searchPath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory.FullName, fileName);
    
    if (File.Exists(searchPath)
    {
        // Do something here (like add searchPath to a List<string>)
    }
    
    currentDirectory = Directory.GetParent(currentDirectory.FullName);
}
```

Comment: What would `currentDirectory.FullName.Dump();` do ?

Comment: Whoops, that was accidentally left over from writing the code in LINQPad. Not necessary, I've removed it.

Comment: Thank you. Can I do this in vfs ? My filePath is of vfs.

Comment: I don't see why not, give it a try.